# How to move other controls when you move one with TranslateTo?

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms

I am doing a control of an entry that when I give a button, a layout appears moving with a translateTo. The entry should be at the bottom of the screen and when pressing the button, the layout should appear from below, moving upwards, moving the entry upwards with it.
[This is an example of how it looks right now](https://gyazo.com/55d407399d9fb49ab240b75103f0f4a4). How should I make XAML to make this possible?

This is my XAML:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<ContentView
    x:Class="ControlProject.CustomControl"
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    x:Name="CustomView">

    <ContentView.Content>

        <StackLayout>
            <!--  ================This is the entry that must be in the bottom================  -->

            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Frame
                    Margin="0,0,0,2"
                    Padding="0,0,0,0"
                    BackgroundColor="{Binding Source={x:Reference CustomView}, Path=FrameColor}"
                    BorderColor="{Binding Source={x:Reference CustomView}, Path=BorderColor}"
                    CornerRadius="{Binding Source={x:Reference CustomView}, Path=CornerRadius}"
                    HasShadow="False"
                    HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>


                        <ImageButton
                            Grid.Column="0"
                            Margin="5,0,0,0"
                            BackgroundColor="Transparent"
                            Clicked="Open"
                            HeightRequest="25"
                            HorizontalOptions="Start"
                            Source="{Binding Source={x:Reference CustomView}, Path=LeftSideIcon}" />


                        <Entry
                            x:Name="EntryControl"
                            Grid.Column="1"
                            Margin="0,0,30,0"
                            HeightRequest="25"
                            HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                            Keyboard="Chat"
                            Placeholder="{Binding Source={x:Reference CustomView}, Path=Placeholder}"
                            Text="{Binding EntryText}"
                            TextColor="{Binding Source={x:Reference CustomView}, Path=EntryTextColor}" />

                        <ImageButton
                            Grid.Column="1"
                            Margin="5"
                            BackgroundColor="Transparent"
                            Command="{Binding Source={x:Reference CustomView}, Path=DeleteMsgCommand}"
                            HeightRequest="25"
                            HorizontalOptions="End"
                            Source="{Binding Source={x:Reference CustomView}, Path=DeleteMessageIcon}" />


                    </Grid>
                </Frame>

                <ImageButton
                    Margin="0,0,5,2"
                    Padding="15,0,10,0"
                    BackgroundColor="{Binding Source={x:Reference CustomView}, Path=SendBtnColor}"
                    Command="{Binding Source={x:Reference CustomView}, Path=SendMsgCommand}"
                    CornerRadius="30"
                    HeightRequest="45"
                    HorizontalOptions="End"
                    Source="{Binding Source={x:Reference CustomView}, Path=RightSideIcon}"
                    WidthRequest="45" />
            </StackLayout>



            <!--  ================This is what it moves up================  -->

            <StackLayout
                x:Name="frameemojis"
                Margin="0,-8,0,0"
                IsVisible="True"
                TranslationY="{Binding Height, Source={x:Reference frameemojis}}">

                <Frame>


                    <CollectionView
                        Margin="-10,-15,-10,-10"
                        HeightRequest="270"
                        ItemsSource="{Binding Source={x:Reference CustomView}, Path=EmojiItemSource}"
                        VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Never">

                        <CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
                            <GridItemsLayout Orientation="Horizontal" Span="5" />
                        </CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
                        <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>



                            <DataTemplate>


                                <ImageButton
                                    Padding="5"
                                    BackgroundColor="Transparent"
                                    Command="{Binding Source={x:Reference CustomView}, Path=EmojiTappedCommand}"
                                    CommandParameter="{Binding EmojiMethodCommand}"
                                    HeightRequest="44"
                                    Source="{Binding EmojiSource}"
                                    WidthRequest="44" />
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>

                    </CollectionView>
                </Frame>
                <!--  ==============  -->
            </StackLayout>
        </StackLayout>

    </ContentView.Content>
</ContentView>
```

This is the method that I use to move the control:

```
   bool state = true;
    void Open(object o, System.EventArgs e)
    {



        if (state)
        {
            state = false;
            frameemojis.TranslateTo(0, 0, 200);
        }
        else
        {
            state = true;
            frameemojis.TranslateTo(0, 1000, 200);
        }

    }
```

Comment: does this help
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/platform/android/soft-keyboard-input-mode

Comment: No. I don't want to move the control when opening the keyboard. I have two elements on screen. The entry with the buttons and then the emoticon menu which moves up when I press a button and when I press it again, it returns down.  I want the entry to be positioned at the bottom of the whole and when opening the menu and move up, it also move with it. And then when it closes, come down with it.

Comment: Here is a similar issue and I had posted the answer , you could check it .https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64749987/how-to-create-a-scrollview-in-this-layout/64751246#64751246