# How to create a ScrollView in this layout?

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms

I need to create a ScrollView in this layout but the problem is that my control occupies the entire screen and I don't know how to make it occupy only the size it has. [This is the functionality of the control](https://gyazo.com/1813b09de680c47cef9e5bd6474a33af)

I need it not to fill the entire screen and only its own size to be able to add more things to the layout

This is the XAML of my control:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<ContentView
    x:Class="ControlProject.CustomControl"
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    x:Name="CustomView">

    <ContentView.Content>

        <AbsoluteLayout>
            <!--  ================This is the entry that must be in the bottom================  -->
            <StackLayout
                x:Name="STACK"
                AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,1,1,0.07"
                AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All"
                Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Frame
                    Margin="0,0,0,2"
                    Padding="0,0,0,0"
                    BackgroundColor="{Binding Source={x:Reference CustomView}, Path=FrameColor}"
                    BorderColor="{Binding Source={x:Reference CustomView}, Path=BorderColor}"
                    CornerRadius="{Binding Source={x:Reference CustomView}, Path=CornerRadius}"
                    HasShadow="False"
                    HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>


                        <ImageButton
                            Grid.Column="0"
                            Margin="5,0,0,0"
                            BackgroundColor="Transparent"
                            Clicked="Open"
                            HeightRequest="25"
                            HorizontalOptions="Start"
                            Source="{Binding Source={x:Reference CustomView}, Path=LeftSideIcon}" />


                        <Entry
                            x:Name="EntryControl"
                            Grid.Column="1"
                            Margin="0,0,55,0"
                            HeightRequest="25"
                            HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                            Keyboard="Chat"
                            Placeholder="{Binding Source={x:Reference CustomView}, Path=Placeholder}"
                            Text="{Binding EntryText}"
                            TextColor="{Binding Source={x:Reference CustomView}, Path=EntryTextColor}" />

                        <ImageButton
                            Grid.Column="1"
                            Margin="0,0,40,0"
                            BackgroundColor="Transparent"
                            Command="{Binding Source={x:Reference CustomView}, Path=DeleteMsgCommand}"
                            HeightRequest="25"
                            HorizontalOptions="End"
                            Source="{Binding Source={x:Reference CustomView}, Path=DeleteMessageIcon}" />

                        <ImageButton
                            Grid.Column="1"
                            Margin="0,0,10,0"
                            Padding="1"
                            BackgroundColor="Transparent"
                            Command="{Binding Source={x:Reference CustomView}, Path=InsertImgCommand}"
                            HeightRequest="25"
                            HorizontalOptions="End"
                            Source="{Binding Source={x:Reference CustomView}, Path=InsertImgIcon}" />


                    </Grid>
                </Frame>

                <ImageButton
                    Margin="0,0,5,2"
                    Padding="15,0,10,0"
                    BackgroundColor="{Binding Source={x:Reference CustomView}, Path=SendBtnColor}"
                    Command="{Binding Source={x:Reference CustomView}, Path=SendMsgCommand}"
                    CornerRadius="30"
                    HeightRequest="45"
                    HorizontalOptions="End"
                    Source="{Binding Source={x:Reference CustomView}, Path=RightSideIcon}"
                    WidthRequest="45" />

            </StackLayout>

            <!--  ================This is what it moves up================  -->
            <StackLayout
                x:Name="frameemojis"
                AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,1,1,0.43"
                AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All"
                TranslationY="{Binding Height, Source={x:Reference frameemojis}}">


                <Frame>


                    <CollectionView
                        Margin="-10,-15,-10,-10"
                        HeightRequest="270"
                        ItemsSource="{Binding Source={x:Reference CustomView}, Path=EmojiItemSource}"
                        VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Never">

                        <CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
                            <GridItemsLayout Orientation="Horizontal" Span="5" />
                        </CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
                        <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>

                            <DataTemplate>

                                <ImageButton
                                    Padding="5"
                                    BackgroundColor="Transparent"
                                    Command="{Binding Source={x:Reference CustomView}, Path=EmojiTappedCommand}"
                                    CommandParameter="{Binding EmojiMethodCommand}"
                                    HeightRequest="44"
                                    Source="{Binding EmojiSource}"
                                    WidthRequest="44" />
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>

                    </CollectionView>
                </Frame>
                <!--  ==============  -->
            </StackLayout>

        </AbsoluteLayout>

    </ContentView.Content>
</ContentView>
```

MainPage.xaml (this is where I want to add the ScrollView):

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage
    x:Class="App24.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:fav="clr-namespace:ControlProject;assembly=ControlProject">


    <AbsoluteLayout>
        <!--  This is where I want to add the scrollview  -->

        <StackLayout
            AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,1,1,1"
            AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All"
            BackgroundColor="#4DFF0000">

            <fav:CustomControl
                x:Name="entrycontrol"
                BorderColor="{Binding EntryBorderColor}"
                CornerRadius="{Binding EntryRadius}"
                DeleteMessageIcon="crossblack.png"
                DeleteMsgCommand="{Binding DeleteMsgCommand}"
                EmojiItemSource="{Binding EmojiList}"
                EmojiTappedCommand="{Binding EmojiTappedCommand}"
                EntryTextColor="{Binding TextColor}"
                FrameColor="{Binding EntryBGColor}"
                InsertImgCommand="{Binding InsertImgCommand}"
                InsertImgIcon="insertimage.png"
                LeftSideIcon="icon.png"
                Placeholder="Escribddame"
                RightSideIcon="send.png"
                SendBtnColor="{Binding SendBtnColor}"
                SendMsgCommand="{Binding SendMsgCommand}" />
        </StackLayout>




    </AbsoluteLayout>

</ContentPage>
```

[EDITED]

Method on code behind control:

```
  bool isShow;
    const double layoutPropHeightMax = 0.45;
    const double layoutPropHeightMin = 0.06;
    private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!isShow)
        {
            //show the keyboard

            Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () =>
            {

                var height = layoutPropHeightMin;

                while (height < layoutPropHeightMax)
                {
                    await Task.Delay(1);
                    height += 0.04;

                    AbsoluteLayout.SetLayoutBounds(bottomBar, new Rectangle(0.5, 1.0, 1.0, height));
                }

            });

        }

        else
        {
            // hide the keyboard
            Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () =>
            {

                var height = layoutPropHeightMax;

                while (height > layoutPropHeightMin)
                {
                    await Task.Delay(1);
                    height -= 0.04;

                    AbsoluteLayout.SetLayoutBounds(bottomBar, new Rectangle(0.5, 1.0, 1.0, height));
                }

            });

        }


        isShow = !isShow;
    }
```

Control XAML:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<ContentView
    x:Class="ControlProject.CustomControl"
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    x:Name="CustomView">


    <AbsoluteLayout AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,1,1,1" BackgroundColor="White">

        <StackLayout
            x:Name="bottomBar"
            AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.5,1,1.0,0.07"
            AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All"
            BackgroundColor="Olive">


            <StackLayout
                x:Name="STACK"
                AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,1,1,0.07"
                AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All"
                Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Frame
                    Margin="0,0,0,2"
                    Padding="0,0,0,0"
                    BackgroundColor="{Binding Source={x:Reference CustomView}, Path=FrameColor}"
                    BorderColor="{Binding Source={x:Reference CustomView}, Path=BorderColor}"
                    CornerRadius="{Binding Source={x:Reference CustomView}, Path=CornerRadius}"
                    HasShadow="False"
                    HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>


                        <ImageButton
                            Grid.Column="0"
                            Margin="5,0,0,0"
                            BackgroundColor="Transparent"
                            Clicked="Button_Clicked"
                            HeightRequest="25"
                            Source="{Binding Source={x:Reference CustomView}, Path=LeftSideIcon}" />


                        <Entry
                            x:Name="EntryControl"
                            Grid.Column="1"
                            Margin="0,0,55,0"
                            HeightRequest="25"
                            HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                            Keyboard="Chat"
                            Placeholder="{Binding Source={x:Reference CustomView}, Path=Placeholder}"
                            Text="{Binding EntryText}"
                            TextColor="{Binding Source={x:Reference CustomView}, Path=EntryTextColor}" />

                        <ImageButton
                            Grid.Column="1"
                            Margin="0,0,40,0"
                            BackgroundColor="Transparent"
                            Command="{Binding Source={x:Reference CustomView}, Path=DeleteMsgCommand}"
                            HeightRequest="25"
                            HorizontalOptions="End"
                            Source="{Binding Source={x:Reference CustomView}, Path=DeleteMessageIcon}" />

                        <ImageButton
                            Grid.Column="1"
                            Margin="0,0,10,0"
                            Padding="1"
                            BackgroundColor="Transparent"
                            Command="{Binding Source={x:Reference CustomView}, Path=InsertImgCommand}"
                            HeightRequest="25"
                            HorizontalOptions="End"
                            Source="{Binding Source={x:Reference CustomView}, Path=InsertImgIcon}" />


                    </Grid>
                </Frame>

                <ImageButton
                    Margin="0,0,5,2"
                    Padding="15,0,10,0"
                    BackgroundColor="{Binding Source={x:Reference CustomView}, Path=SendBtnColor}"
                    Command="{Binding Source={x:Reference CustomView}, Path=SendMsgCommand}"
                    CornerRadius="30"
                    HeightRequest="45"
                    HorizontalOptions="End"
                    Source="{Binding Source={x:Reference CustomView}, Path=RightSideIcon}"
                    WidthRequest="45" />

            </StackLayout>

            <!--  ================This is what it moves up================  -->
            <StackLayout
                x:Name="frameemojis"
                AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,1,1,0.43"
                AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All"
                TranslationY="{Binding Height, Source={x:Reference frameemojis}}">


                <Frame>


                    <CollectionView
                        Margin="-10,-15,-10,-10"
                        HeightRequest="270"
                        ItemsSource="{Binding Source={x:Reference CustomView}, Path=EmojiItemSource}"
                        VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Never">

                        <CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
                            <GridItemsLayout Orientation="Horizontal" Span="5" />
                        </CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
                        <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>

                            <DataTemplate>

                                <ImageButton
                                    Padding="5"
                                    BackgroundColor="Transparent"
                                    Command="{Binding Source={x:Reference CustomView}, Path=EmojiTappedCommand}"
                                    CommandParameter="{Binding EmojiMethodCommand}"
                                    HeightRequest="44"
                                    Source="{Binding EmojiSource}"
                                    WidthRequest="44" />
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>

                    </CollectionView>
                </Frame>
                <!--  ==============  -->
            </StackLayout>


        </StackLayout>



    </AbsoluteLayout>

</ContentView>
```

[This is how I want to make it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VeDar.png)

Answer (score 0):

In the ContentPage  because you set the height of Stacklayout as the whole screen

```
AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,1,1,1"
```

So it will be an expected result .

Actually , in your case you could implement the effect without using ScrollView .

#### in ContentPage

```
<AbsoluteLayout BackgroundColor="White" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,1,1,1">
        <!--  -->

        <Button Clicked="Button_Clicked" Text="Test"  AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.5,0.3,0.2,0.05" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" />

        <StackLayout x:Name="bottomBar" BackgroundColor="Olive" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.5,1.0,1.0,0.04" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All">
            

            <!-- put the content of emoji keyboard and entry here -->

        </StackLayout>
    </AbsoluteLayout>
```

#### In Code behind

```
    bool isShow;
    const double layoutPropHeightMax = 0.45;
    const double layoutPropHeightMin = 0.06;
   //you could set the height here as you want

    private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(!isShow)
        {
            //show the keyboard

            Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () =>
            {

                var height = layoutPropHeightMin;

                while (height < layoutPropHeightMax)
                {
                    await Task.Delay(1);
                    height += 0.04;

                    AbsoluteLayout.SetLayoutBounds(bottomBar, new Rectangle(0.5, 1.0,1.0, height));
                }

            });

        }

        else
        {
            // hide the keyboard
            Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () =>
            {

                var height = layoutPropHeightMax;

                while (height > layoutPropHeightMin)
                {
                    await Task.Delay(1);
                    height -= 0.04;

                    AbsoluteLayout.SetLayoutBounds(bottomBar, new Rectangle(0.5, 1.0, 1.0, height));
                }

            });

        }


        isShow = !isShow;
    }
```

And in Custom Control let the Entry and Keyboard fill the whole StackLayout .

[image]

Comment: I tried to do this with this code but I don't know why the emoji keyboard don't appear. Only go up the entry. And why the movement is too laggy? Is there a way to make this smoother?

Comment: You need to set the keyboard fill the custom control .

Comment: Horizontal and vertical options in fill and expand?

Comment: You could share your sample on github and  I will test it on my side .

Comment: I solved it, is there a way to make it smoother? Looks laggy like this: https://gyazo.com/7491208e8647781bb06f8dace0e892dd

Comment: Try to set height += 0.02;

Comment: I tried 0.02 but is slower because Task delay is 1. I can't make it smoother :/ .

Comment: Or you could use some third party library .

Comment: This is my github reporitory:  https://github.com/IsmaCTO84/Keyboardexample     This is my  original code using translate instead of your code. My problem is that I can't use the scrollView. How Can I fix that

Comment: It is not the best solution with scrollview in your case .

Comment: I need to have the control with the emoji keyboard and the entry and then, in the mainpage, the control with a scrollview in the background to do whatwever I want and the entry stay in the bottom of the screen. I don't know If Im explaining it well

Comment: I had posted my solution .

Comment: It has not served me :(

Comment: From your post it seems that you had used my solution . What the problem is ?

Comment: I have the custom control and then, in addition, another project in which I import the control and use it. I have to make an entry that stays at the bottom and opens a menu of emoticons but in that project the entry control must be at the bottom and then it must be possible to add other elements on the screen, so that the control that I import does not occupy the entire screen , just occupy below. My idea is to add the control and above it a scrollview to add information, it is not for the operation of the control.
I posted an image in my updated post to show you how I want this,

Comment: You could check my screen shot ,it implement the similar effect as you want .