# How to hide a part of the page,after the action of the command?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have a listview in the content view,and I want to after refreshing hide a part of the page.Please help me to it.I tried to make a swipe but listview conflict with it.so I decided to try make with refresh

```
 <ContentView.Content>
        <controls:CustomFrame CornerRadius="25,25,0,0" Margin="0" Padding="10" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"  VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
           


            <StackLayout Padding="0">
                <BoxView HorizontalOptions="Center"  WidthRequest="40" HeightRequest="7"  BackgroundColor="Gray" CornerRadius="15"  />


                <!-- <StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                    <SwipeGestureRecognizer Direction="Up"  Command="{Binding RefreshCommand}"  ></SwipeGestureRecognizer>
                </StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>-->
                <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding MyPins}" RowHeight="100" x:Name="ListPlaces"  IsPullToRefreshEnabled="True"   RefreshCommand="{Binding RefreshCommand}"
           IsRefreshing="{Binding IsRefreshing}"
                       SelectionMode="None">

                    <ListView.ItemTemplate >
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ViewCell>
                                <ViewCell.View>
                                    <Frame CornerRadius="10" BackgroundColor="LightBlue" Padding="10">
                                    <StackLayout  Orientation="Vertical" Padding="0">
                                        <StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                                            <TapGestureRecognizer  CommandParameter="{Binding .}"    Command="{Binding BindingContext.CallPlace, Source={x:Reference ListPlaces}}"  ></TapGestureRecognizer>
                                        </StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                                        <Label x:Name="NameOfPlace" Text="{Binding Name}" TextColor="#2D78FD" FontSize="14" FontFamily="Robobo"/>
                                        <Label x:Name="AdressOfPlace" Text="{Binding Address}"  TextColor="#616161" FontSize="12" FontFamily="Robobo"/>
                                        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                                            <Label x:Name="TimeWork" VerticalOptions="Center" Text="Open until  -  "  TextColor="#616161" FontSize="12" FontFamily="Robobo"/>
                                            <Label x:Name="TimeWork1" VerticalOptions="Center" Text="{Binding Opened}"  TextColor="#616161" FontSize="12" FontFamily="Robobo"/>
                                            <Image Source="openIcon" VerticalOptions="Center" />
                                            <Button HeightRequest="24" VerticalOptions="Center" Padding="0,-3,0,0" WidthRequest="92" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand" FontSize="14" CornerRadius="45" BackgroundColor="#2D78FD" TextColor="White" Text="Call up"/>
                                        </StackLayout>

                                    </StackLayout>
                                    </Frame>
                                </ViewCell.View>
                            </ViewCell>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                </ListView>
            </StackLayout>
           
        </controls:CustomFrame>

    </ContentView.Content>
```

WHAT I WANT TO DO
[image]

[image]

Comment: So that's two issues: conflict of scrolling, how to hide part of the overlay page. Check [bindable-layouts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/bindable-layouts) for scrolling, and [translation animation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/animation/simple#translation) or bind height property to hide.

Answer (score 1):

Since you had used MVVM , there are many ways which can implements .

**Option 1 :**

We could set the **IsVisible** property of the ViewCell

#### in xaml

Define the property in the model

```
public class YourModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    bool isVisible;
    public bool IsVisible
    {
        get
        {
            return isVisible;
        }

        set
        {
            if(value!=isVisible)
            {
                isVisible = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("IsVisible");
            }
        }
    

        //other property like name...

}
```

In ViewModel

```
CallPlace = new Command((org)=> {

       YourModel model = org as YourModel;
       model.isVisible = false;

});
```

#### Option 2

You could remove the item from **MyPins**

```
CallPlace = new Command((org)=> {

  YourModel model = org as YourModel;
  MySource.Remove(model);

});
```

Comment: I want to hide a part of the page.Because I want to leave part of the page to make then a swipe action to return the page to its previous state and make it large again

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64749987/how-to-create-a-scrollview-in-this-layout/64751246#64751246 .