# Xamarin Forms - Multiple views on one page

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

So i need to achieve [Multiple Views on a page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GlKDb.png), [Something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UU3K9.png), but i cant seem to find a way that makes this possible cross-platform. I can see that on IOS you can achieve this by adding multiple viewcontrollers to a page, but is this achievable in xamarin forms?

Please let me know if you have any experience with this.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many solutions which can implement it . For example , you could use **AbsoluteLayout** to create a swipe  view .

#### in ContentPage

```
<AbsoluteLayout BackgroundColor="White" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,1,1,1">
        <!--  -->

        <Button Clicked="Button_Clicked" Text="Test"  AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.5,0.3,0.2,0.05" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" />

        <StackLayout x:Name="bottomBar" BackgroundColor="Olive" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.5,1.0,1.0,0.04" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All">
            

            <!-- put the content of swipe here -->

        </StackLayout>
    </AbsoluteLayout>
```

#### In Code behind

```
    bool isShow;
    const double layoutPropHeightMax = 0.45;
    const double layoutPropHeightMin = 0.06;
   //you could set the height here as you want

    private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(!isShow)
        {
            //show the keyboard

            Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () =>
            {

                var height = layoutPropHeightMin;

                while (height < layoutPropHeightMax)
                {
                    await Task.Delay(1);
                    height += 0.04;

                    AbsoluteLayout.SetLayoutBounds(bottomBar, new Rectangle(0.5, 1.0,1.0, height));
                }

            });

        }

        else
        {
            // hide the keyboard
            Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () =>
            {

                var height = layoutPropHeightMax;

                while (height > layoutPropHeightMin)
                {
                    await Task.Delay(1);
                    height -= 0.04;

                    AbsoluteLayout.SetLayoutBounds(bottomBar, new Rectangle(0.5, 1.0, 1.0, height));
                }

            });

        }


        isShow = !isShow;
    }
```

Here is a similar [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64749987/how-to-create-a-scrollview-in-this-layout/64751246#64751246) that you can have a refer .